# Convert the output of a custom function from the default StringType to mapType in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a nested pyspark SQL query. In the subQuery, I use a custom function that returns a dictionary where the parent query will use explode, to expand this dictionary result.
The problem is that eventhough I return a dictionary , the main query will see this column type as stringType and explode wont work.

```python
def ff(k,vList):return dict([(k+v,v) for v in vList])

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b=1),Row(a=1, b=2)])
df2.registerTempTable("ttt2")
sqlContext.registerFunction('ff',ff)
spark.sql("select a ,(bb) from (select a,ff(a,collect_list(b)) as bb  from ttt2 group by a)").show()
+---+----------+
|  a|        bb|
+---+----------+
|  1|{2=1, 3=2}|
+---+----------+
```

but  when I use explode in the main query

```python
spark.sql("select a ,explode(bb) from (select a,ff(a,collect_list(b)) as bb  from ttt2 group by a)").show()
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'explode(__auto_generated_subquery_name.`bb`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string; line 1 pos 10;\n'Project [a#178L, unresolvedalias(explode(bb#294), None)]\n+- SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name\n   +- Aggregate [a#178L], [a#178L, ff(a#178L, collect_list(b#179L, 0, 0)) AS bb#294]\n      +- SubqueryAlias ttt2\n         +- LogicalRDD [a#178L, b#179L, mapfield#180], false\n"
```

How do I convert the function's output to mapType or ArrayType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the return type for a user defined function. By default, `registerFunction()` will set the return type to `string`. If 
 you type `help(sqlContext.registerFunction)`, you'll see:

> registerFunction(self, name, f, returnType=StringType)
>
> ...
>
> In addition to a name and the function itself, the return type can be optionally specified.
>       When the return type is not given it default to a string and conversion will automatically
>       be done.  For any other return type, the produced object must match the specified type.

In your case, you'll need to do:

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext.registerFunction('ff',ff,returnType=MapType(StringType(),IntegerType()))

spark.sql(
    "select a,bb from (select a,ff(a,collect_list(b)) as bb from ttt2 group by a)"
).show()
#+---+-------------------+
#|  a|                 bb|
#+---+-------------------+
#|  1|Map(2 -> 1, 3 -> 2)|
#+---+-------------------+

spark.sql(
    "select a,explode(bb) from (select a,ff(a,collect_list(b)) as bb from ttt2 group by a)"
).show()
#+---+---+-----+
#|  a|key|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#|  1|  2|    1|
#|  1|  3|    2|
#+---+---+-----+
```

Here I used `MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())` to specify that it's a map of strings (keys) to integers (values). You may want to modify those according to your actual data.

Comment: NP. I'm assuming your actual problem is more involved, but you could avoid the `udf` and get the same output doing `df2.withColumn('key', f.col('a') + f.col('b')).select('a', 'key', f.col('b').alias('value')).show()` where `f` is `pyspark.sql.functions`